# How to apply styling to bootstrap datetimepicker time icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to apply styling to the datetimepicker time icon.  Mine seems to pull to the left and it doesn't have a hover colour so it is a little un-intuitive to use.  As you can see from the picture below:

[image: datetimepicker]

How can I make it hover and center, something like this:

[image: what i want it to look like]

I have added a datetimepicker CSS but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: include your codes not just images..

Comment: did you ever get this sorted? i am having the same issue... exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the css of   **.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td span**

for example

```
   .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td span{
        background-color: darkblue !important;
        display: block !important;
        float:none !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
```